# Cordova IOS Won't Build

Tags: ios, cordova, cocoapods

I am currently trying to get a cordova project to run on ios (already working on android)

I have setup osx in a virtual machine and i am using a shared folder to use the same files as the android version on windows.

I have had many issues with trying to build it on ios though. It seems to fail no matter what i do.
I tried to remove the ios platform and re-add it on the osx side but this always failed. So i added it on the windows side but then when i tried to install the pods (on osx side) i get this error.

> Errno::EACCES - Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Volumes/VMware
>   Shared
>   Folders/APPNAME/platforms/ios/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/CHANGELOG.md

The windows shared folder give full permissions to everyone so file permissions should not be an issue.

It seems confusing to me as the script actually creates the file that it for some reason doesn't have permission for.

I should also note that this is my first time using osx so i am kind of cludging my way through it.

Answer (score 1):

If it fails under OSX and it works on Windows it's probably because **something is missing** on your OSX environment that will be required during the build.

Creating the platform under Windows to build on OSX only postpones the problem by a few minutes.

I advise you to try to solve the problems on OSX and if you can't, open a new topic on stackoverflow